# How do I append text to a specific position of JTextArea (Java)?

Tags: java, string, swing, jtextarea

I have a determined text in a `JTextArea` and want to add text to a specific position (**more specifically, before every line feed**), depending on a user's action.

Example:

> Lorem ipsum
>
> Dolor sit amet

To:

> Lorem ipsum {text here}
>
> Dolor sit amet {another text here}

I tried `JTextArea.append(String)` method, but it doesn't give me the option of choosing where to place the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`JTextArea.insert(String,int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#insert-java.lang.String-int-) which:

> Inserts the specified text **at the specified position**. Does nothing if the model is null or if the text is null or empty.